# Do you need a Pull down resistor when the line has an LED connected?

Tags: led, pulldown

basically, since the LED is a diode that is tied to GND via a Resitor, does that mean it can double as Pull-down resitor for that line?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJ6uJy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What makes you think the data bus needs a pulldown? What else is connected to it?

Comment: Do you understand the purpose of a pull-down?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally a LED will not suffice, because when the voltage drops down to the forward voltage of the LED, the LED mostly stops conducting, therefore the voltage will not drop much further (or at least very slowly). Depending on your application this might not be sufficient.

Comment: To clarify, since the OP asked two opposite questions, an LED and resistor will not function as a pulldown. You answered the question in the body, not the reverse question in the title.

Comment: Thanks. I've slightly reworded my answer to make it less ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

If you need your bus to have pull-downs, and have LEDs with 1k resistors connected to ground, this arrangement won't provide you a "true" pull-down. This is because the LED will have a 1.5-2V range where its impedance will be very high (due to their characteristic I-V curve), and unpredictable pin leakages might drive some signals above logic "1" threshold. Therefore, if you want your design to operate reliably across all design corners and have good board yields in production, you will still need 10-20-50k (whatever the I/O pad needs) pull-downs, either directly to ground, or in parallel with each LED.